# Reading a String that belongs to this family: {a^p b^p | p>0}, based on the stack data structure

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, stack

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

class Node {
        public:
          int data; 
          Node* next; 

          public: Node(int d) {
            data=d;
            next=NULL;
          }; 
}; 


class Stack { 
      Node *head; 

      public: Stack() { 
      head = NULL; 
      }; 

   ~Stack(){
   while (head) {
      Node * temp = head;
      head = head->next;
      delete temp;
   }
}

    void push(int data); 
    int pop(); 
    bool isEmpty();
    void print();
}; 

void Stack::push(int data) {
        Node * temp = new Node(data);
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
      }

      int Stack::pop() { 
      if(head!=NULL){
        int x=head->data;
        Node * temp = head;
        head=head->next;
        delete temp;
        return x;
      } else {
        cout << "The stack is empty!";
        return -1;
      }
      }

      bool Stack::isEmpty() {
         return head==NULL;  
     } 

     void Stack::print() {
        Node * temp = head;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp=temp->next;
         }
     }

int main() { 
    Stack St1, St2;
    char c;
    string Str;
    int i, a, length = 0;
    int n, p;
    bool flag = true;

    cout << "Enter the String, use this form: np (n is the number and p is             the power)\n";
    cout << "Press the Enter key when you're done.\n";

    getline(cin, Str);

    for(i=0; Str[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        c=Str[i];
        if(c == ' ')
           continue;
        if(c=='-'&&Str[i+1]!='\0')
        {
           i++;
           c=Str[i];
           a=((int)c - '0') * -1;
           St1.push(a);
           length++;
        }
        else{

           a=(int)c - '0';
           St1.push(a);
           length++;
       }
    }
    if(length%2 != 0)
    a = St1.pop();  /* To make sure the String that was entered has an even  length (i.e. a number and its power) */

    if(length == 0)
       cout << "Your string didn't include any numbers!\n";

    while(!St1.isEmpty() && flag) 
    {
       p = St1.pop();
       n = St1.pop();

       if(p > 0)
         St2.push( (int)n );
       else
         flag = false;
    }
    if(flag)
       St2.print();
    else
       cout << "Your string doesn't belong to the family; {a^n b^n | n>0}";

    cin >> a;
    return 0;
```

}

This program should reads a String that belongs to this family: {a^p b^p | p>0} based on the stack data structure. p is the power.. so if p > 0 it displays the values of a and b.. So in this case: " 2352 " a = 2, p = 3, b = 5, and p =2.. since p > 0.. 2 and 5 should be printed.

Comment: Your stack isn't very efficient. A `std::vector` would use less memory allocations.

Comment: Your design seems to have a lot of unnecessary limitations. Are you sure, that you want to allow only numbers from range [0; 9]? Why didn't you introduce **proper** semantics for power syntax? I would suggest you to assume strings with format of `a^b` and use `^` character as a split position. Then `a` and `b` would be allowed to have any integer value. Also, your stack could be improved. If you **really** need to do it this way - fine, but `std::vector` or `std::stack` with nice memory pool would be much better (i.e. faster).

Comment: I don't get that error. When I run it and enter 2352 as input it outputs " 50 53 ".

Comment: @username_unavailable yeah these are the ASCII codes for 2 and 5.. How can I convert them to normal integers? I've edited the code and forgot to edit the paragraph..

Comment: Just cast them to characters when you print them in the Stack::print function.